# Is there a way to use Vim as multiline grep?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to run Vim from shell script and to get in `stdout` the matched pattern?

For example let's search for `function(x,y,z)` but also for

```
function(
   x, y, z)
```

The straight approach `vim -es -c ":g/function(\_.\{-})/p" -c ":q!" file.c` prints only the first line.

How can we print the whole pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a range to the `:print` command, e.g. the current line and the line where a closing parenthesis matches:

```
vim -es -c"g/function(\_.\{-})/.,/)/p" -c"q!" file.c
```

Here `.` is the current line (where `:global` matches) and `/)/` is the line where `)` matches. Minor caveats are that we match within a match and we need to repeat the last character of the match.

See [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) for the `/{pattern}/` range.